# create array with foreach() result on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying for two days to create an array with the result of a mysql query as values ​​to prevent a  appears:

```
foreach($achievements as $acvhm2){
    if(!array_key_exists(($acvhm2['key'] - 19999 ), $achievements)){
        if($acvhm2['key'] - 20000 == $tam){
        $san .= $tam.',';
        $san1 = substr($san, 0, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

> $orgly2 = array($san1);

```
if(!in_array($tam, $orgly2)){
echo ' <tr><td style="opacity:.64;">... ';
}
```

but it doesn't work for all the < tr > that I got on results...

when I do the array manually everything works perfectly:

```
$orgly2 = array(3,5,13);
```

all results where $tam is equal to one of the numbers in the array are left with opacity 64.

anyone have any idea what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `explode()`:

```
$orgly2 = explode(',',$san1);
```

You were basically creating an array with one argument that is a string with commas that would look something like this:

```
$orgly2 = array('3,5,13');
```

Comment: thanks for answering! But every time that I use the implode I got many errors on page... Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\achievements.php ...

Comment: My mistake... I used the wrong function.  Sorry.  It has now been updated.

Comment: OBS: the $san prints 3 results: 3, 5 and 13.